# making the form dim while opening another form + delphi

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm using Delphi 10.1 for developing android mobile application. And I'm having two form: Form-A and Form-B. Form-A contains the button and Form-B contains panel with the text. And When I clicks the Form-A button, it should show the Form-B. At that time Form-A should become dim. How can I able to implement this? Please help me.

Comment: Android app with two forms?

Comment: How are you displaying the "Form B" (`Show()` or `ShowModal()` or...)? Are you doing anything specifically to make sure "Form B" does not cover "Form A" (In mobile apps, all forms cover the whole screen by default)? Have you tried using Tab control instead of another form? What is your end goal? What are you trying to achieve? Your "Form B" sounds a lot like `MessageDlg()` to me.

Comment: I'm using FormB.Show;
Form-B contains Taniindicator and the panel which will be showing as 'Please wait'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this with a TRectangle placed on the form I want to dim, set it's Align property to Contents, then set its Fill property and Opacity to achieve the desired amount of dimming.